# Two Mice, capturing exclusively one mouse using Raw Input Model (C++/Visual Studio 2013/Win 8.1)

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, hid, raw-input

How do I configure to read a specific mouse when two mice are connected? I am trying to use one of them as a sensor and the other as a regular mouse. Right now it reads both the mice (not simultaneously,though). I am using the WM_Input model to register and read. 
I did search for the answers here, one of the post used DirectInput method for the same problem. I would appreciate if you can post a link if it's already been answered. Thanks.

```
void OnRawInput(bool inForeground, HRAWINPUT hRawInput){
UINT dataSize;
GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

if (dataSize == 0)
    return;
if (dataSize > m_RawInputMessageData.size())
    m_RawInputMessageData.resize(dataSize);

void* dataBuf = &m_RawInputMessageData[0];
GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RID_INPUT, dataBuf, &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

const RAWINPUT *raw = (const RAWINPUT*)dataBuf;
if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE){
    HANDLE deviceHandle = raw->header.hDevice;
    const RAWMOUSE& mouseData = raw->data.mouse;
    USHORT flags = mouseData.usButtonFlags;
    short wheelDelta = (short)mouseData.usButtonData;
    LONG x = mouseData.lLastX, y = mouseData.lLastY;

    wprintf(L"Mouse: Device=0x%08X, Flags=%04x, WheelDelta=%d, X=%d, Y=%d\n",
    deviceHandle, flags, wheelDelta, x, y);
}
```